# Easier way to add tiles to a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I am adding some tiles to my JFrame for my terrain generator, and it looks like this:

```
        for (double[] row : Terrain.tileData) {
        for (double d : row) {
            if (d >= 10000D) {
                add(new Tile(0, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 9500D) {
                add(new Tile(1, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 9000D) {
                add(new Tile(2, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 8500D) {
                add(new Tile(3, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 8000D) {
                add(new Tile(4, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 7500D) {
                add(new Tile(5, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 7000D) {
                add(new Tile(6, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 6500D) {
                add(new Tile(7, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 6000D) {
                add(new Tile(8, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 5500D) {
                add(new Tile(9, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 5000D) {
                add(new Tile(10, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 4500D) {
                add(new Tile(11, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 4000D) {
                add(new Tile(12, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 3500D) {
                add(new Tile(13, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 3000D) {
                add(new Tile(14, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 2500D) {
                add(new Tile(15, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 2000D) {
                add(new Tile(16, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 1500D) {
                add(new Tile(17, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 1000D) {
                add(new Tile(18, tileSize));
            } else if (d >= 500D) {
                add(new Tile(19, tileSize));
            } else {
                add(new Tile(20, tileSize));
            }
        }
    }
```

and my tile class looks like this:

```
    public Tile(int color, int tileSize) {
    setVisible(true);
    setOpaque(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(tileSize, tileSize));
    if (color == 0) {
        setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    } else if (color == 1) {
        setBackground(new Color(138, 132, 125));
    } else if (color == 2) {
        setBackground(new Color(105, 100, 94));
    } else if (color == 3) {
        setBackground(new Color(77, 71, 64));
    } else if (color == 4) {
        setBackground(new Color(36, 32, 27));
    } else if (color == 5) {
        setBackground(new Color(69, 53, 42));
    } else if (color == 6) {
        setBackground(new Color(82, 48, 4));
    } else if (color == 7) {
        setBackground(new Color(17, 82, 4));
    } else if (color == 8) {
        setBackground(new Color(24, 115, 6));
    } else if (color == 9) {
        setBackground(new Color(56, 143, 39));
    } else if (color == 10) {
        setBackground(new Color(51, 156, 30));
    } else if (color == 11) {
        setBackground(new Color(29, 156, 3));
    } else if (color == 12) {
        setBackground(new Color(37, 201, 4));
    } else if (color == 13) {
        setBackground(new Color(67, 237, 33));
    } else if (color == 14) {
        setBackground(new Color(87, 85, 0));
    } else if (color == 15) {
        setBackground(new Color(176, 141, 2));
    } else if (color == 16) {
        setBackground(new Color(232, 195, 39));
    } else if (color == 17) {
        setBackground(new Color(224, 200, 101));
    } else if (color == 18) {
        setBackground(new Color(79, 67, 222));
    } else if (color == 19) {
        setBackground(new Color(36, 18, 227));
    } else if (color == 20) {
        setBackground(new Color(15, 0, 179));
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Also, is there a way to allow this to `pack()` faster?

Comment: Something like: new Tile((100000-d)/500, tileSize)? Similarly, try to identify the pattern in your color arguments and turn it into an equation.

Answer (score 1):

For the tilegeneration:

```
for(double d : row){
    înt v = 20 - d / 500;
    if(v < 0)
        v = 0;

    add(new Tile(v , tileSize));
}
```

Store the colors in an array and read them like this:

```
Color[] colors = new Color[]{}
setBackgroundColor(colors[color]);
```

Comment: setBackgroundColor(colors[color]); creates an error

Comment: have you initialized the array with values (my code is just for demonstration, colors should probably be a `static final` variable of `Tile`)

Comment: my array is declared like this (Simplified quite a bit):Color[] colors = new Color[]{
            new Color(255, 255, 255), new Color(123,456,789)};
It is underlining the setBackgroundColor portion of the code

Comment: where do you define the variable? should be something like this: `public class Tile{ private static final Color[] colors = new Color[]{...};}

Comment: I moved it from in  method to outside, but my method extends JPanel, do I need to do anything special?

Comment: "cannot find symbol" is a syntax error. if the variable is visible from inside your method everything should work

Comment: I wrote the values to the array in the method without a problem, but it still doesn't like the setBackgroundColor

Comment: sry, just noticed the error isn't caused by `colors`, but by `setBackgroundColor(...)`. this method doesn't exist. replace it with `setBackground(...)`

Comment: That fixed the syntax error, but there was an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error

Comment: check, if the array has `length == 21` and `color` holds a valid value

Comment: I did it, it printed out the values normally, escept it printed java.awt.Color[r=36,g=18,b=227] a lot of time

Comment: could you pls post the new code, would simplify the whole thing a lot

Comment: for (double[] row : Terrain.tileData) {
            for (double d : row) {
                int v = (int) (20 - d / 500);
                if(v < 0) {
                    v = 0;
                }
                add(new Tile(v, tileSize));